# Delete last used line in txt file

Tags: powershell, foreach

first time poster here, but you helped me a lot before. I don´t know how to ask google this question.

I have a powershell script, where with foreach command i check every computer in .txt that contains computer names. (Short explanation is that in check bitlocker status, connection avalability etc.) Everything works fine, but since I fall in love with powershell recently and try to automate more and more thing, that i should upgrade this script little more.

I have foreach ($DestinationComputer in $DestinationComputers) and after i check everything i wanted, i want to delete that row in .txt file.

Can someone help? I am still learning this and got stuck.

Comment: Not quite sure what you intend to do... The title says to delete the last line in a text file, but your question is about reading a file with computernames, perform checks on these and after that delete the **current** line ?? Please elaborate and show some examples

Comment: Sorry, i try to explain more.

Comment: my script starts like this

$DestinationComputers = txt file with list of computers
foreach ($DestinationComputer in $DestinationComputers)

Then this script check bunch of different data and get me results. In the end of the script i would like to add something that delete computer name ($DestinationComputer) from that txt file ($DestinationComputers).

Comment: Then I would recommend reading that textfile, do whatever you need to get from that computer and only if that **fails** somewhere, output the computername and capture that in a variable. Finally write that collection of computernames to a (new) file. That way, you will effectively remove the **sucesful** lines, because you do not add these to the capturing variable.

Comment: May I know the purpose of deleting computer name from the text file

Comment: @NarayanaLvsl sure. One reason is, that since not all computers are available at the same time, I need to run this script again on them. But its not necesary to run this script again on computers that already were online and i have desired output from them. This way my txt file with list of computers will be shorter after every try bcs it will delete computers i already checked.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, I suggest creating a list of computernames that did not process correctly, while discarding the ones that did not fail.
By doing so, you will effectively remove the items from the text file.

Something like this:

```
$DestinationComputers = Get-Content -Path 'X:\somewhere\computers.txt'
# create a list variable to store computernames in
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

# loop over the computer names
foreach ($DestinationComputer in $DestinationComputers) {
    # first check: is the machine available?
    $succes = Test-Connection -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($succes) {
        # do whatever you need to do with that $DestinationComputer
        # if anything there fails, set variable $success to $false
        <YOUR CODE HERE>
    }

    # test if we processed the computer successfully and if not, 
    # add the computername to the list. If all went OK, we do not
    # add it to the list, thus removing it from the input text file
    if (-not $success) {
        $list.Add($DestinationComputer)
    }
}

# now, write out the computernames we collected in $list
# conputernames that were processed OK will not be in there anymore.
# I'm using a new filename so we don't overwrite the original, but if that is
# what you want, you can set the same filename as the original here.
$list | Set-Content -Path 'X:\somewhere\computers_2.txt'
```